# How to place different sized widgets side by side?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I have the following widgets which define to scrollbars with text:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

# -------------
# set_up_output_scrollbar
def set_up_output_scrollbar():
    output_scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
    output_scrollbar_text = Text(root, height=scrollbar_height, width=scrollbar_width)
    output_scrollbar.config(command=output_scrollbar_text.yview)
    return output_scrollbar, output_scrollbar_text


# -------------
# set_up_calculations_scrollbar
def set_up_calculation_scrollbar():
    calculation_scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
    calculation_scrollbar_text = Text(root, height=calculation_scrollbar_height, width=calculation_scrollbar_width)
    calculation_scrollbar.config(command=calculation_scrollbar_text.yview)
    return calculation_scrollbar, calculation_scrollbar_text
```

Example on setup:

```
# -------------------------------------------
# PROGRAMM SET UP
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # ---------------------------
    # main definition of gui
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Wetterderivate und Klima v_a0.0.1')
    #icon_path = get_local_path()
    #root.iconbitmap(icon_path + 'icon.ico') # icon
    root.geometry("1920x1080")
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False)


    # ---------------------------
    # call initial functions and set inital values
    scrollbar_width = 75
    scrollbar_height = 15
    calculation_scrollbar_height = 25
    calculation_scrollbar_width = 100

    # -------------
    # output_scrollbar
    output_scrollbar, output_scrollbar_text = set_up_output_scrollbar()
    output_scrollbar_text.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky='NS')
    output_scrollbar.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky='NS')
    # -------------
    # calculation_scrollbar
    calculation_scrollbar, calculation_scrollbar_text = set_up_calculation_scrollbar()
    calculation_scrollbar_text.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky='NS')
    calculation_scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=5, sticky='NS')

    root.mainloop()
```

How I can place them independed of each other side by side? Above the `output_scrollbar` are a lot of buttons and menus so when I place the `calculation_scrollbar` it shows like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the arguments `columnspan` and `rowspan` to have one of the widgets spanning over several rows and columns. In your case, the Text widget and the scrollbar on the right should span several rows:

```
calculation_scrollbar.grid(row=1, rowspan=6, column=5, sticky='NS')
```

At least I gather that 6 rows should suffice, given the other scrollbar resting at row 6. Just give the text-widget the same rowspan or it will look awkward.

EDIT: Sometimes it may also be a good idea to use Frame-widgets to organize your window. In your case, I would recommend three frames (top left, bottom left, right). Each of the frames then has its own grid.

Comment: Thank you! I will implement frames as well :)